# If my passport is stamped to stay in the UK for six months, can I ship my furniture over?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, moving

I've come over as a visitor to the UK. I might be staying longer than planned and would love to ship my furniture over if possible because it will be cheaper than continuing to store it in the US. My passport is stamped for "leave to enter for six months."

Comment: This might (very probably) give the impression that you’re moving permanently to the UK https://www.gov.uk/moving-to-uk

Comment: Does UK customs check the visa status of the package recipient?

Comment: @AzorAhai. I don't believe so. However, changing your plans significantly from what was said in a landing interview can cause serious problems on subsequent visits, due to the credibility problem.

Comment: @origimbo I am just totally missing how anyone would connect a furniture delivery to the OP's status. Mainly, I find it hard to believe the government is well-organized enough to track that sort of thing. But, I've never been to the UK, so maybe that's something they'd pick up on?

Comment: @AzorAhai Oh, I'm not saying that there'll be any problems with importing things, beyond the customs fees, but a "leave to enter for six months" stamp shouldn't be interpreted as the UK being happy for a visitor to suddenly change their plans from staying for one month to staying for 6. And *that* information does get tracked (mostly).

Comment: `because it will be cheaper than continuing to store it in the US.` How on earth is this possible?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen my thoughts exactly.  I pay every month for a storage space of maybe 20 or 30 cubic meters roughly half as much as I had to pay to ship about one cubic meter of stuff from the Netherlands to the US.  Perhaps the pricing works out differently with the larger volumes that are implied by "furniture."

Comment: @phoog I still do not see how it could be cheaper because don't forget these items are going to be shipped both ways. Very interesting.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen It might be a rented resdential property when "storage" is involved ;) - though all I am doing is speculating here.

Comment: @phoog - it has been some time, but back about 1993 I recall it cost me about 1000 guilders to ship a cubic meter from Amsterdam to the US. I can rent a pretty large storage unit in the US for several years for that.

Comment: @JonCuster I live in New York City.  Storage space is rather more expensive here.

Comment: @phoog - fair enough, but you could store stuff out in remote New Jersey, particularly if you aren't going to be around much. Instead of being 5000 km from your stuff you would be 5100 km away from it...

Comment: @JonCuster my stuff is in Queens; I'm in Brooklyn, about 10 km from it.  The added inconvenience of getting to my stuff in New Jersey would outweigh the savings.

Comment: This seems a pretty silly approach. Why don't you ship your furniture to The desert in Nevada? storage space is nearly free there, they keep whole airplanes for 40$ a month.

Answer (score 4):

You can ship your furniture at any time, regardless of your immigration status.

However, you may be required to pay import  duties and taxes on your furniture, depending on the nature and value of the items. Reliefs are available, but there will be some paperwork involved to claim them. You might also be required to provide some security against the import taxes for the duration of your stay. It'll be this process that ties your import to your visa status.

The government notice that details the rules can be found [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notice-3-bringing-your-belongings-pets-and-private-motor-vehicles-to-uk-from-outside-the-eu/notice-3-bringing-your-belongings-pets-and-private-motor-vehicles-to-uk-from-outside-the-eu), and the shipping company will be able to provide advice too.

Note, though, that if you stay significantly longer than you declare on landing it can cause problems. If you declare a visit of, say, a month, and you stay for six then on your next visit the immigration officer will want to know how you supported yourself. If you can't present a watertight explanation then the officer may conclude you were working illegally and deny you entry. Be careful.

Comment: The immigration officer can also conclude that the traveler had deployed deception at the previous landing interview, so someone in this situation, even with perfectly clear self-sufficient finances, should be prepared to document that plans changed after being admitted.

Comment: Are you sure of this? Our experience in Israel was that furniture could not be brought in without a long-term visa.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus if that were the case, it would be very tricky for UK citizens to import anything, since unlike Israel, there's no UK mandated ID.

Comment: @origimbo While there's no requirement to have ID, I'd be surprised if a shipping company would release cargo to someone who didn't have any.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus That's going to come down on whether you consider a credit card ID.

Comment: @phoog: Some people have a rather... spontaneous lifestyle and could plausibly make this sort of decision at the drop of a hat.  But if the immigration personnel have just your word to go on, they might not like that explanation very much.

Comment: Ouch.  That should have been "employed deception," not "deployed deception."  Blasted autocorrect!